# react typescript generate html from string - onclick

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have some problem creating board with onclick events
im creating some string like:

```
 for(let i=0;i<8;i++){
        boardTable += '<tr><th></th>'
        for(let j=0;j<8;j++){
            const cellId = `${i}_${j}`
            boardTable+=`<td className="light" id="${cellId}" onClick="onCellClicked(${cellId})"></td>`
        }
    boardTable += '</tr>'
}
```

and in the end i use HtmlReactParser from

```
import HTMLReactParser from "html-react-parser";
```

and in the end i display using parser and function generateBoard (which mainly do the for loop)

```
   <div className="column">
        {HTMLReactParser(generateBoard(boardType.playerShipsBoard))}
        </div>
```

but have problem

[image]

and the onclick has not been added
[image]

how should i do that ?

Comment: there is an issue opened in the github repo of the library : https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser/issues/73, you can find an example of how to fix this problem in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/remarkablemark/kvgz36eh/1/

Comment: How about doing this the React way and using JSX instead of this?

Comment: how can i do it with jsx?